# let $m(x) = x^3 + 4x + 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$. find polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ so that $(x-3) f(x) = (x - 3)g(x)$ (mod m(x))

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $m(x) = x^3 + 4x + 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$. find polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ so that $$(x-3) f(x) = (x - 3)g(x)\pmod {m(x)}$$

but

$$f(x) \ne g(x) \pmod {m(x)}$$

my solutiion, need help finishing up the answer

factor $m(x) = (x^2 + x + 3)(x - 2) * 0\pmod {m(m)}$

but

$$x^2 + x + 3 \ne 0 \pmod {m(x)}$$

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $m(x)$ and not $m(m)$?

Comment: But it is not clear what you mean by "factor $m(x)=\dots$"

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that in $ \mathbb{F}_5$, we have

$$ x^3 + 4x + 1 = (x-3) ( x^2 + 3x + 3) $$

As such, the condition is satisfied if and only if $f(x) \equiv g(x) \pmod{ x^2 + 3x + 3 }$. In particular, $ f(x) = 0 $ and $ g(x) = x^2 + 3x + 3$ will work.

Answer (score 0):

This one is almost only about understanding what congruence means.

What you want is $(x-3)f(x)-(x-3)g(x)=(x-3)(f(x)-g(x))=m(x)q(x)$ for some $f,g,q$.

How can you make $(x-3)(f(x)-g(x))$ a multiple of $m(x)$? Notice that if you are allowed to choose $f$ and $g$ then the factor $f(x)-g(x)$ is anything you want? How can you choose that factor to make it a multiple of $m(x)$?